# MVC Testing actions that rely on HTTPContext

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, testing, httpcontext

I have a project where I need to provide action tests. My approuch has been to ensure actions do not rely on anything they do not receive as parameters, maing use of ValueProviders and ModelBinders. As such I would pass in HTTPContextBase etc.

However, I now have an action which uses a static class that is a wrapper around HTTPContext to accesses Session and Identity. Thus it seems I have to mock out HTTPContext to test this action. Not too complicated, I guess, but it just feels wrong.

My gut feeling is that the static class should be redeveloped to be instantiated with HTTPSessionStateBase and IPrinicple and use them as internal stores. Then I could instantiate this wrapper in my action, from action parameters, making the action and the wrapper class much more testing friendly.

Would this be a recommended approuch or does anyone have any other ideas, were I would not have to change my static class to instance ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) to mock a HttpContext is just the way you might want to try it out.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{

    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    context.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

    HomeController controller = new HomeController();

    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext( context , new RouteData(), controller );

    ....
    ...........
}
```

**Updated:**
In the case if you want to mock HttpSession(as gdoron mentioned in comment). It is not really complicated since you are MOCKING something doesn't means you have to build entire, real object and all of its properties.

Suppose that your controller will

1. Checks whether user is authenticated.
2. Gets identity name.
3. Gets a value from Session["key"].
4. manipulates cookie.

The code could be like that:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    ......
    .........
    var mockedControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext> ();
    mockedControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Session["key"]).Returns("A value in session");
    mockedControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);    
    mockedControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns("An identity name");
    mockedControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Response.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection ());

    HomeController controller = new HomeController();
    controller.ControllerContext = mockedControllerContext.Object;
    .....
    ......

}
```

Comment: It's very complex to achieve what you wrote when trying to mock the session!

Comment: The problem is that Contoller's HttpContext is set from the static ASP.NET HttpContext. So simply building HttpContextBase and attaching it to Controller's context does not affect the static HttpContext. My action calls a static wrapper, which does not have access to ControllerContext and accesses ASP.NET HttpContext directly. Unless I am misisng something, I feel this design is flawed and the static wrapper should be redeveloped as an instance that takes the controller's HttpContext, then I could mock the life out of it ... If I choose.

Comment: I think you are right. Since you've chosen to take things which was saved in static. You've lost flexibility.(But it might get the benefit of saving some resources)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using ***MvcContrib - testhelpers***
Learn how to use from [CodePlex](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper)
You can download it from [nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcContrib.Mvc3.TestHelper-ci) or directly from CodePlex
Good luck!

Comment: Had a quick look at them, and particular to my situation, it seems you are able to build up a controller context, but there does not appear to be anything that initializes ASP's HTTPContext.Current. Therefore when my action calls the static wrapper class, which, in turn attempts to access HTTPContext.Current.Session, I get an error. I guess I will just have to go through the pain of initializing HTTPContext.Current in my tests ?

Comment: @ricardo it's look like you don't use DI. Inject the httpContext and all your problems will disappear... it's a mistake to use the static httpContext.Current, you can see it in your's situation. Good luck!